# GCP task queue deadlock or threading issue

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, task-queue, google-app-engine-python

I'm trying to test some async logic on GAE standard (localhost) and something is deadlocking until I kill the server, and then I see this stack-trace.

All feedback appreciated!

```
INFO     2019-03-25 22:47:22,304 module.py:861] task: "POST /community/news/forge HTTP/1.1" 500 -
WARNING  2019-03-25 22:47:22,304 taskqueue_stub.py:2149] Task task2 failed to execute. This task will retry in 0.100 seconds
Exception in thread Thread-2:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 801, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python@2/2.7.15_1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/threading.py", line 754, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 2182, in MainLoop
    self._ProcessQueues()
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 2127, in _ProcessQueues
    response_code = self.task_executor.ExecuteTask(task, queue)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/api/taskqueue/taskqueue_stub.py", line 2059, in ExecuteTask
    '0.1.0.2')
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 757, in add_request
    inst)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/dispatcher.py", line 843, in _handle_request
    request_type=request_type)
  File "/Users/dgaedcke/gcloud_tools/google-cloud-sdk/platform/google_appengine/google/appengine/tools/devappserver2/module.py", line 820, in _handle_request
    logservice = apiproxy_stub_map.apiproxy.GetStub('logservice')
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'apiproxy'
```

Comment: I don't think there is a whole lot to go on here.  Are you able to do some further debugging to identify the source statement that is failing, blocking, looping?  If you can't use a debugger, maybe instrument the code with print statements until the offending area is narrowed?

Comment: Thanks Kolban!!   Correct me if I'm wrong, but I was thinking print statements would not work for code running on other threads?  I suspected they did not have access to Stdout for the terminal but I will see what I can uncover.  And also, it seems that it's the task queue itself (GAE internal code) that is blocking so I'm not sure my print stmts will be reached.